# Assets throwing PHP error with BetterWorkflow

Tags: matrix, assets, better-workflow

I'm using

- EE 2.6.1
- Assets 2.1.3
- BetterWorkflow 1.6.2.5
- Matrix 2.5.5

I'm working with the BWF team too, but since their developer is out for the week, they recommended I also check here.

I've had no problem publishing entries so far, but when I activate Better Workflow and hit the Publish button, I get the following:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: entry_id

Filename: assets/ft.assets.php

Line Number: 799

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /export/vol2/httpd/htdocs/research/ee/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /export/vol2/httpd/htdocs/research/ee/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 414
```

Comment: Hey there,

so is Assets within a Matrix field there or just a standalone Assets field?

Comment: Assets in a Matrix field.

Comment: It's been a long time since you asked this question - have you been in touch with BWF folk? Also, can you try upgrading Assets to 2.1.4 first to see if this has been fixed?